# Why doesn't lint tell me the line number and nature of the parse error?

Tags: php, lint

I'm calling php lint from a Windows batch file, like so:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.php) do php -l %%f
```

When a file contains a syntax error, it only outputs `Errors parsing xxx.php`. Is there any way to get it to tell me what the nature of the error is, and what line it's on? Maybe another switch?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've accepted Charles's answer, but thought I should add a couple of details, as I had to do some extra hunting to find out what to do.

The problem was that I wasn't seeing the `stderr` output, so I started by adding `2>&1` to the end of the relevant commands. This still didn't help, so I realised that the problem was that PHP wasn't outputting stderr stuff at all. I went to the PHP install directory and looked in php.ini and found that by default, `display_errors` is `Off`. Changed it to `On` and it now works.

Comment: Oh my, that was unexpected.  You'd think that *asking PHP to check the syntax of a file* would, by default, report syntax errors!  Keep in mind that you can manipulate php.ini arguments from the command line using the `-d` option:  `php -d display_errors=1 -l foo.php`

Comment: thanks for the tip! (please accept this answer, not the incorrect one above ;-)

Answer (score 43):

If you get the "Errors parsing foo.php" message without any details, you can force both relevant error output directives as parameters when you run PHP lint:

```bash
php -d display_errors=1 -d error_reporting=4 -l foo.php
```

Example:

```
[somewhere]# php -l submit.php

Errors parsing submit.php

[somewhere]# php -d display_errors=1 -d error_reporting=4 -l submit.php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in submit.php on line 226
Errors parsing submit.php
```

As per [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting), `display_errors` needs a truthy value, and `error_reporting` can be set to `4` (`E_PARSE`) because that's the only type linting will report.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you using?  As of 5.3, line numbers are included in lint output:

```
[charles@server ~]$ cat syntax_error.php
<?php
echo "This line is legal\n";
echo I'm a syntax error!\n;
echo "This line never gets reached.\n"

[charles@server ~]$ php -l syntax_error.php
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ',' or ';' in syntax_error.php on line 3

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ',' or ';' in syntax_error.php on line 3
Errors parsing syntax_error.php
[charles@server ~]$
```

The error appears twice because it's going to both stdout and stderr.  It's been a *long* time since I've worked with batch files on Windows, maybe the version you're using only emits the error on stderr, and the batch file is discarding the output of stderr?

Comment: This helped me find out what the problem was, so I've accepted it. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Can you accept the answer that you posted below since it actually explains the issue?

Comment: @Hammerite Please do switch around the Accepted flag - I'd delete this answer to make it more obvious, but you can't self-delete an accepted answer.